# Display part of record Linux command

Tags: linux, grep, command

I need to search an apache log for an error code and when that code is found display only the IP address on that line? Using a Linux command.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the log you want to parse and a sample of the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty hard to answer without more details, like what the "code" is you're looking for, and where on the corresponding lines the ip addresses are, whether the lines with the code in question *always* have an ip address on the same line, whether they sometimes have more than one, and you need all of them, and so on. Do you need to allow IPv6 addresses or only IPv4?

If you need to match both IPv4 or IPv6 then adapting the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses) on stackoverflow, you could use something like:

```
grep -E '[PATTERN]' access.log | grep -E -o -e '((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])' -e '(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))'
```

Replace '[PATTERN]' with the RegEx you need to search for.

Here the `-E` flag is for extended regex, which makes things easier. The first grep instance filters the log to lines containing your '[PATTERN]'. The second grep instance looks for the IP address, and uses `-o` to only output the part of the line that matches the appropriate format. The first `-e` expression is for IPv4 and the second `-e` expression is for IPv6.

The RegEx for IPv6 is a monster.

It might be possible to simplify to only one grep instance, but we'd need more details about the log format (or at least I would).